# Compute mean of two stars objects in R

Tags: raster, r, sf, stars

I have two `stars`-objects and I simply would like to calculate the mean for each pixel.
I am not really sure how to do that and if my approach is correct. At the moment I'm doing the follwing:

I have

```
> jan
stars object with 2 dimensions and 1 attribute
attribute(s):
  mean_no_na     
 Min.   :0.27    
 1st Qu.:0.82    
 Median :1.01    
 Mean   :1.15    
 3rd Qu.:1.44    
 Max.   :3.69    
 NA's   :194505  
dimension(s):
  from  to  offset delta  refsys point values    
x    1 641  605720   250 unnamed    NA   NULL [x]
y    1 643 5220237  -250 unnamed    NA   NULL [y]
```

and

```
> feb
stars object with 2 dimensions and 1 attribute
attribute(s):
  mean_no_na     
 Min.   :0.28    
 1st Qu.:0.64    
 Median :0.80    
 Mean   :0.85    
 3rd Qu.:1.06    
 Max.   :1.93    
 NA's   :194505  
dimension(s):
  from  to  offset delta  refsys point values    
x    1 641  605720   250 unnamed    NA   NULL [x]
y    1 643 5220237  -250 unnamed    NA   NULL [y]
```

and now I'd like to simply compute the mean. The two two rasters cover exactly the same geographic extent and are just for the month of january and february. For that I'm doing:

```
c = c(jan, feb, along=3)
mean_two_month = st_apply(c, c("x", "y"), mean)
```

But I'm not really sure if this is the correct approach.

Comment: Seems like a fine approach to me...

Comment: Agree with @JoshO'Brien, seems perfectly fine